# How to Install Ubuntu with MBR?

Tags: 11.10, windows, windows-7, bootloader

Hello all, I have a very good question and I hope you can help me:

As you know there 2 or maybe 3 ways to install Ubuntu, the 2 ways that I know are:

- Bootable Installation Ubuntu CD/DVD
- Ubuntu Wubi Installer

When you install from the CD/DVD by logical and previously you should have a free hard drive space or a unpartitioned space for installing Ubuntu and also have Windows OS installed first , the problem is that when you install the GRUB/GRUB2 (Ubuntu or Linux Boot loader) it delete the Windows MBR (Master Boot Record). Wubi dont have problem that, because you installed inside Windows as a App and make a folder in you Windows OS, but Wubi have many limitations like:

- Disk Space Limitation, some times you what more that 31 GB
- Low Swap Space, you have to re size your Swap space, if you like to use Ubuntu as a Virtualization Environment or Development Enviroment and many more

As I was saying, the installation from the CD/DVD it seems better, it recognizes your PC Hardware very well, it gives proper Swap Space and has more Ubuntu Full experiences plus don't have Wubi limitations like dose above, but if you have a Windows issue like booting up issue, it is harder to solve that windows issue because GRUB doesn't because he already delete the MBR and don't let you pressing the F8 key or enter on Windows System Recovery.

So what I want, if it is possible, is this have a Ubuntu Partion (in my case 60GB) but let you boot from the MRB like Wubi instead of GRUB.

My system Specs:

- Dell Studio 1558
- Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Below are more technical System Specs see it from Windows , RAM , Processor and More:

[image: My Dell 1558]

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm understanding your question correctly:

If you dual boot with Windows 7, installing Grub to the MBR is, in my opinion, the best option. Yes, your typical Windows loader is overwritten, but can easily be restored in case you want to get rid of the Ubuntu installation. As for assigning 60GB for your installation, the Ubuntu installation lets you do that easily.

If you ever want to restore the windows loader, just boot up with your Windows 7 recovery disc, assuming you have made one, and go through the typical steps to get to the command prompt. There, type in the following one at a time:

bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot

....then reboot

Your Windows loader is now restored and you can now boot into Windows. From there, you can delete the partitions once used by Ubuntu, and use the emptied space for Windows.

Hope this helps.......

Answer (score 1):

There is a software, EasyBCD that does exactly what you're looking for. I used it before, and it is quite easy to use, but it's a little too long to describe precisely how it works here. Probabily you'll be interested in this guide: http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu